# Restoring Deleted Pages in Kentico Error

Tags: kentico

First time SO user here. Redirected from Kentico site to see if someone may know the answer to this. Could not locate the info in their KB articles.

Trying to restore a deleted page from the recycling bin on our site. The only option that exists in Kentico's admin UI is to restore it back to the page's original location. Unfortunately, the page tree has changed substantially and the restore function will not work as a result. It generates the following error:

*An unexpected error occurred, see event log for more details. Event source: Content, Event code RESTOREDOC*

I'm wondering if I recreate the path, is that the solution to restoring this particular page? I would then move it to its new location and then delete the parent pages. There are basically 4 levels of navigation above this particular page's original location, so I'm concerned about recreating these on the live site unless that really is going to be what works.

Definitely appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: What is the error in the event log?

Comment: This is my first time digging into the event log. This is the main line. Not sure if you need the other text or not.

Message: [VersionManager.RestoreDocumentInternal]: The node cannot be restored because its parent node no longer exists.

Comment: I would try recreating the path first, making sure that the alias path (the unique path used in Kentico) matches the previous path. If you have any documents named the same as the previous documents you deleted, you may have conflicts here. For example, "/about-us" may be "/about-us-(1)" so be sure to check the alias path on the properties of the new parent page when attempting the restore. Beyond that, if you don't have any backups, I'm not sure what to try next. You may be able to create a query in the database that would show you the contents of the page without doing an actual restore.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try.

Comment: @DaveyDean is that page important to you because of data/content or functionality/design? If last one - you should be able find appropriate page template and use it on newly created page: design, markup, functionality sits in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before by recreating the (NodeAlias)Path.

Taken from the full source code for restoring documents in Kentico version 9:

```
var parentNode = TreeProvider.SelectSingleNode(site.SiteName, TreePathUtils.GetParentPath(restoreNode.NodeAliasPath), TreeProvider.ALL_CULTURES, false, null, false);
```

Kentico uses the parent path of the NodeAliasPath of the deleted document in the recycle bin to determine the original location.

Recreating that structure based on the NodeAliasPath allows you to restore the documents. Please ensure that the NodeAliasPath exists via the properties of the page and ensure that parent page type allows the deleted page type as a child.

Good luck!